# How to set up RabbitMQ to handle asynchronous tasks on the same resource across consumers such as database updates?

Tags: postgresql, rabbitmq, message-queue, distributed-computing

For example, we have a queue of tasks that handle a number and 2 consumers:

```
             |-> c1
[5,4,3,2,1] - 
             |-> c2
```

When a message is consumed, let's say it performs some asynchronous action such as updating a number in a database.

```
my_number_table
---
number(int)
```

If consumer 1 gets task 1 and starts to update the row in the database, and consumer 2 gets task 2 and starts to update the same row in the database, won't the database lock?

I believe I would like task 2 to not get picked up by any consumer until task 1 is completed and the number has been successfully saved into the database first.

Answer (score 0):

- You can solve your problem by creating two different queues for two consumers. and send all the dependent tasks to the same queue. and also make sure only one consumer is accessing that queue. for example, if you want task2 should start only after the task1 and sent both of them same queue queue1.
- you can solve your problem by using one queue for both consumers and acquiring a lock on the database. but still, you can't assure the execution order is maintained. for instance, consumer1 has very high latency and consumer2 has low latency so task2 will reach consumer2 before the task1 reaches consumer1. By the time the consumer1 acquiring the lock the consumer2 might have the finished the task2.

---

**So from my understanding it's better to send the dependent task to the same consumer.**

Comment: I understand and agree with the idea of "task2 should start only after the task1 and sent both of them same queue queue1", but how do I limit it so that if I have 2 or more consumers to queue1, they only do one task at a time and wait for each other? Cause they normally try to saturate as many as they can and don't wait for each other. It sounds like I need to set `prefetch: 1`?

Comment: setting prefetch to 1 won't also work in your case if you have 2 or more consumers because if 2 starts at the same time then task1 will assign to the consumer1 and task2 will assign to consumer2 and those two perform the tasks in parallel.

Comment: And one more suggestion read about the rabbitmq exclusive queue and check whether that will satisfy your needs.

Comment: Oh, I see. I mixed up `prefetch` with `exclusive`. Ok so with 1 queue, prefetch 1, 2 consumers, it'll distribute 1 message at a time to both consumers, which can then execute at the same time, and conflict. `exclusive` sounds like more what I need, but it seems there is a difference between exclusive queue and exclusive consumer. Exclusive queue locks the queue to the connection that created it, but what I think I want is exclusive consumer, which locks so that one connection can execute a task at a time?

Comment: Yes, you can use exclusive consumer for your need. but be sure you're the first one who joining queue otherwise you will be blocked until the already existing consumer leaves the queue.